# Tkinter toplevel: Opening treeview to fit the frame

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, toplevel

Am having challenge letting my treeview fill the toplevel window have created have tried fill= "x" and fill="both" but not getting the result.Any suggestion to do this.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def my_treeview():
    mt = tk.Toplevel()
    mt.geometry("1000x580")

   tree = ttk.Treeview(mt)
   tree.insert("", "0", "item1", text="fill width")
   tree.insert("", "1", "item2", text="fill height")

   tree.pack(fill="both")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

treeview = tk.Button(root, text="open treeview", command=my_treeview).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fill="both"` means "fill all the area that has been allocated to you". It is doing just that. The treeview widget has a certain height it wants to be, so pack allocates just enough space for it to fit. That leaves a lot of extra space that has not been allocated.

If you want the treeview to *expand* to fill all remaining space and not just the space that it needs, use the `expand` option in addition to the `fill` option.

Example:

```
tree.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: This  question has been down voted i think it will be encouraging  to state the reason for me not to repeat again.

Comment: @ADWAN: how am I supposed to know why it was downvoted? My guess is because the question shows no signs of you doing any research before asking the question. You're expected to do a lot of research before asking. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)